# $('...').modal is undefined when using webpack with separate configs for library code and my code

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, bootstrap-modal, angular2-components

I'm having an issue in opening modals with the $('#modal-id').modal('show') function in an Angular 2/4 component. After narrowing down the issues, I think it has something to do with my webpack loading the jquery and bootstrap dependencies.

I have two webpack configs. One runs to bundle all of my angular components etc and the other compiles all of my dependencies.

This is my webpack.config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;

module.exports = (env) => {
// Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
const sharedConfig = {
    stats: { modules: false },
    context: __dirname,
    resolve: { extensions: [ '.js', '.ts' ] },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] },
            { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
};

// Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    entry: { 'main': './ClientApp/main.ts' },
    output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
    plugins: [
       // new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery', jquery: 'jquery' }),
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
        // Plugins that apply in development builds only
        new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
            filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
            moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
        })
    ] : [
        // Plugins that apply in production builds only
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ])
});
return [clientBundleConfig];
};
```

And this is my webpack.vendor.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = (env) => {
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');
const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
const sharedConfig = {
    stats: { modules: false },
    resolve: { extensions: [ '.js' ] },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
        ]
    },
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            '@angular/animations',
            '@angular/common',
            '@angular/compiler',
            '@angular/core',
            '@angular/forms',
            '@angular/http',
            '@angular/platform-browser',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
            '@angular/router',
            'ag-grid-angular/main',
            'ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css',
            'ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-fresh.css',
            'bootstrap',
            'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
            'es6-shim',
            'es6-promise',
            'event-source-polyfill',
            'jquery',
            'zone.js',
        ]
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: '[name]_[hash]'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery', jquery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular\b.*\b(bundles|linker)/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14898
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^vertx$/) // Workaround for https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/100
    ]
};

const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    output: { path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist') },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: extractCSS.extract({ use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' }) }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS,
        new webpack.DllPlugin({
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
            name: '[name]_[hash]'
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ])
});
return [clientBundleConfig];
}
```

Originally. In my component when i called $('#modal-id').modal('show') from my component i got $ is undefined. I resolved this by adding the following line into my webpack.config.js (I already had it in my vendor config)

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery', jquery: 'jquery' })
```

Now jquery appears to work fine,  however, the bootstrap extensions do not seem to work.

I have spent a number of days looking at other issues that are similar such as:

[Modal is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40496364/modal-is-not-a-function-error-using-webpack-and-bootstrap-loader)

[Bootstrap plugins firing "is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43724658/webpack-2-jquery-and-bootstrap-plugins-firing-is-not-a-function#comment76668500_43724658)

but there are either no answers or none that work in my case.

Hoping someone can help.

One last thing. The webpack set up was done using the Angular spa .net core template from Mads Kristensen found here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ASPNETCoreTemplatePack